# Solve multitenant login at scale

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, multi-tenant, google-cloud-iam

I'm in a real build or buy struggle. GCP identity platform would serve almost all our needs.

Basically I want to build usermanagement on my own (including rbac and groups) and ONLY want to solve Login and tokens with the below requirements. I know quite a bit about jwt and authentication in general. The question I'm asking my self is just of its better to build a solution on my own or to use one existing.

Is there any alternative which supports the following:

- multi tenancy (at scale >10k tenants)
- MFA
- social login
- SSO with oidc and saml
- and of course persistence (using refresh tokens)

Are there any tipps for self building? Are there any alternatives? Any direction is greatly appreciated

PS:

None of these are what I need: Ory, keycloak, okta, auth0, fusionauth, gluu

Comment: Frontegg is great because of its multi-tenancy features, but you can go with any of the ones you mentioned with some workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

**USER DATA**

When you integrate OAuth there are always 2 sources of user data:

- The identity data's view of users
- Your own business data's view of users

I think what you are saying is that you want finer control over user data, while also externalising difficult security work.

**TOKENS AND CLAIMS**

The identity system should be able to include values such as `Tenant ID` in access tokens, regardless of which data source each value is stored in.

Similarly the `User ID` in your business data is also likely to be needed in tokens. This value should be provided to your APIs in a consistent way, regardless of how the user signs in, and this is managed via account linking.

**DESIGNING END-TO-END FLOWS**

The main thing is to think through how these will work, for both new and existing users. This [detailed Curity article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/integrate-identity-business-data/) provides some worked examples.

**CHOOSING A SOLUTION**

Don't choose a third party identity system until you've designed your end to end flows and clarified your requirements. The key thing about OAuth is that it requires extensible building blocks, rather than being an out of the box solution.

Some companies start with home grown identity microservices, which can become a lot of work, but may be ok in the early days. I always recommend keeping application code portable, so that you can migrate to a better provider in future, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only considering open source solutions? Azure AD ticks all of your boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not implement security logic like authorization or authentication or encryption yourself. IMO its always better to use an existing solution - especially features like MFA are not trivial to implement.

> None of these are what I need: Ory, keycloak, okta, auth0, fusionauth, gluu

Why is that? It seems to me most of those are a good option for you - especially the open source ones